# How to re-enable Nouveau After installing NVIDIA Graphics Driver incorrectly on Kali Linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

After seeing tutorials on kali.org for NVIDIA Drivers and install it:

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)

apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

It is written to unable Nouveau and update GRUB using the following command:

```
sed 's/quiet/quiet nouveau.modeset=0/g' -i /etc/default/grub
```

*update-grub*

After reboot it became laggy.

and i enter the ff. command as the tutorial says to check if its okay:

```
glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"
```

direct rendering: Yes(Commandline Response)

please help to enable it again.

Comment: Why Kali? It is not a distribution for starters.